# Converting CodeIgniter query to Laravel query

Tags: mysql, laravel, codeigniter, query-builder

I have the following code in CodeIgniter

```
$html = array();
        $sqltourtypes = 'SELECT * FROM tourtypes ORDER BY nTourTypeID ASC';
        $sqltours = 'SELECT * FROM tours WHERE nTourTypeID = ? ORDER BY _kpnID ASC';

        $tourtypes = $this->db->query($sqltourtypes)->result();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($tourtypes); $i++){
            $html[] = '<li><a href="#">'.$tourtypes[$i]->_kftDescription.'</a>';
            $tours = $this->db->query($sqltours,array($tourtypes[$i]->nTourTypeID))->result();
            if(count($tours)>0){
                $html[] = '<ul>';
                for($ia = 0; $ia < count($tours); $ia++){
                    $html[] = '<li>'.$tours[$ia]->tDescription.'</li>';
                }
                $html[] ='</ul></li>'; 
            }else {
                $html[] = '</li>';
            }   
        }
        return implode('',$html);
```

I recently had to switch to Laravel framework. I couldn't make my query work in Laravel. Basically I have two tables, tourtypes and tours. _kftDescription is used to list the tour types under the ul tags and tDescription is used to list tour names under the specific group as a li tags.

I always get an error when trying to convert the query. Can anyone suggest how to implement my code from CodeIgniter? Where nTourTypeID's are "1" they belong to Tour Type "Cruises". Hope makes sense.

[image]

**Update:** My app\Http\Controllers\BookingsController.php file looks like this

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Bookings;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator as Paginator;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Validator, Input, Redirect ; 
class BookingsController extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
  $tourTypes = collect(DB::table('tourtypes')->orderBy('nTourTypeID')->get())
        ->map(function ($item) {
            $item->tours = DB::table('tours')->where('nTourTypeID', $item->nTourTypeID)->get();

            return $item;
        });

        return view('bookings', compact('tourTypes'));

    }
```

and routes for bookings looks like this (my route is bookings I don't have a route tours):

```
Route::get('bookings','BookingsController@getIndex');
```

and finally \resources\views\bookings\index.blade.php file looks like this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
{{--*/ usort($tableGrid, "SiteHelpers::_sort") /*--}}
@if(count($tourTypes))

    <ul>
        @foreach($tourTypes as $tourType)
            <li>
                <a href="#">{{ $tourType->_kftDescription }}</a>

                @if(count($tourType->tours))
                    <ul>
                        @foreach($tourType->tours as $tour)
                            <li>{{ $tour->tDescription }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                @endif
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>

@endif
```

I still get the error

> Undefined variable: tourTypes (View:
>   D:\XAMPP\htdocs\bookings\resources\views\bookings\index.blade.php)

When I write

```
$tourTypes = DB::table('tourtypes')->orderBy('nTourTypeID', 'ASC')->get();
print_r($tourTypes);
```

Prints

> Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array (
>   [0] => stdClass Object ( [nTourTypeID] => 1 [_kftDescription] =>
>   Cruises [_kftColourID] => 003399 ) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaMES.png) => stdClass Object (
>   [nTourTypeID] => 2 [_kftDescription] => 4WD [_kftColourID] => ) [2] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [nTourTypeID] => 3 [_kftDescription] => Pearl Farm
>   [_kftColourID] => 00ccff )

So, the query is working but I cannot print ul and li tags with the values using;

```
@if(count($tourTypes))
    <ul>
        @foreach($tourTypes as $tourType)
            <li>
                <a href="#">{{ $tourType->_kftDescription }}</a>
                @if(count($tourType->tours))
                    <ul>
                        @foreach($tourType->tours as $tour)
                            <li>{{ $tour->tDescription }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                @endif
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Is there an error message? If so, what does it say?

Comment: First I got `Undefined property: Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine::$db (View: C:\XAMPP\htdocs\bookings\resources\views\bookings\index.blad‌​e.php)`  then changed `$tourtypes = $this->db->query($sqltourtypes)->result();` to `$tourtypes = DB::table('tours')->get();` now I get this eror: `ErrorException in e1cff7d5e9e0d2f02a08975fab510e441de69bc5.php line 39: Undefined property: stdClass::$_kftDescription` just endless different errors.  I referred to https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries but cannot run the query

Comment: Why use a framework at all, if you don't use the given tools? The proper way in laravel would be to define models and relations. The controller code would be much simpler. And HTML code should be moved to the templates.

Comment: I am working on a crud project. I had to switch to laravel I have the models. Everything is working fine but this query.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel version 5.1

Comment: first write models, then define relations inside models, and then write some code in controller. It's even easier than you think. Show us laravel code, maybe then we can help. It may be something like Tourtype::with('tours')->get(); And tours will be the function inside Tourtype model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that this answer is just to give you an example of what you can do in Laravel.

Say your url for the route is `/tours` you could do something like:

```
Route::get('tours', function () {

    $tourTypes = collect(DB::table('tourtypes')->orderBy('nTourTypeID')->get())
        ->map(function ($item) {
            $item->tours = DB::table('tours')->where('nTourTypeID', $item->nTourTypeID)->get();

            return $item;
        });

    return view('tours', compact('tourTypes'));
});
```

Then create a the file `resources/views/tours.blade.php` and add the following:

```
@if(count($tourTypes))

    <ul>
        @foreach($tourTypes as $tourType)
            <li>
                <a href="#">{{ $tourType->_kftDescription }}</a>

                @if(count($tourType->tours))
                    <ul>
                        @foreach($tourType->tours as $tour)
                            <li>{{ $tour->tDescription }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                @endif
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>

@endif
```

The above example will only output the ul. This tutorial should help you a little more:
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/5

---

Furthermore, as @PaulSpiegel mentioned in the comments it would be more beneficial for you to use `Eloquent` ads it reduces code in your routes/controllers and also helps with eager loading.

To do this you can create the following files:

app/Tour.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tour extends Model
{
   protected $primaryKey = 'kpnID';

    public function Tourtypes()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Tourtype::class, 'nTourTypeID', 'nTourTypeID');
    }
}
```

app/Tourtype.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tourtype extends Model
{
    /**
     * The primary key for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'nTourTypeID';

    /**
     * Tours Relationship
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function tours()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tour::class, 'nTourTypeID', 'nTourTypeID');
    }
}
```

In the above I'm assuming that the primary key for tours is `kpnID`. If it isn't then just change it.

Then your route could look something like:

```
Route::get('tours', function () {

    $tourTypes = \App\Tourtype::with('tours')->get();

    return view('tours', compact('tourTypes'));
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#defining-a-layout

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much you are the best :)

Comment: I was sure that It would work but I got an error Undefined variable: tourTypes (View: C:\XAMPP\htdocs\bookings\resources\views\bookings\index.blade.php...

Do I put the first code `Route::get('tours', function () {` in bookings\routes\module.php ?

Comment: I don't know what `bookings\routes\module.php` is. I would imagine you're getting this error because you're not passing `tourTypes` to your view e.g. return view('bookings.index', compact('tourTypes'));.

Comment: @hijacker83 Change `compact('tourType')` to `compact('tourTypes')` so that it matches the variable name.

Comment: Updated... Can you please see my updated post? I still have the error Undefined variable: tourTypes though.

Comment: Desperetely need a help. Any suggestions please?

Comment: @hijacker83 You try running `php artisan view:clear`. The only other suggestion I would make is changing return `view('bookings', compact('tourTypes'));` to return `view('bookings.index', compact('tourTypes'));` if the path to your blade file is resources/views/bookings/index.blade.php.